# How can I populate a ComboBox with Queue elements?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, queue, populate

I've been trying to figure out how to populate a combobox with multiple elements from a queue for a while. Can someone tell me how to do it?

I'm using JavaFX (no scenebuilder) and the latest version of Java. I've tried using an iterator, but I've only been able to successfully populate one element into the combobox.

```
i1.getItems().addAll ( //combobox code
            "Solve for",
        //queue elements here
);


//interator code. Other class calls it.
itrVelocity = velAns.iterator();

    while (itrVelocity.hasNext()) {
        SPH3U.velocity = itrVelocity.next();
    }
```

if queue has the following element [2.3, 4.2, 7.1], then the combobox should display in order from top to bottom "Solve for", "2.3", "4.2", "7.1".

However, I've been only successful in getting the combobox to display "Solve for", "7.1".

Any solutions are appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to include `"Solve for"` as item. Usually you use put a lable with text like this next to the combo or use it's `promptText` property. (If you want to allow the user to input new elements by selecting this item, just ignore this comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need to iterate the `Queue` and put the elements in the `ObservableList`.

```
ComboBox<String> box = new ComboBox<>();
box.getItems().add("Solve for");

// Assuming generic type of Queue based on your question
Queue<Double> queue = ...; // get instance from somewhere
while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
    box.getItems().add(queue.remove().toString());
}
```

Or, if you don't want to drain the `Queue`, you can do:

```
for (Double element : queue) {
    box.getItems().add(element.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, your solution is great!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using stream :

```
    ComboBox<String> cBox = new ComboBox<>();
    cBox.getItems().add("Solve for");
    cBox.getItems().addAll(queue.stream().map(String::valueOf).
                                                       collect(Collectors.toList()));
```